# Constant changes in time series model

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, robust-standard-error

I am estimating a time series model using OLS.  The LHS variable has a downtrend across the period. There is certainly autocorrelation on both the LHS and RHS.

the regression is:

$us10yr = \alpha + \beta_1 {X} + e_t $

I have split the periods up and have found that the constant has significant variation across the sample. This is probably best seen from the below chart (which shows a rolling 4yr window).

[image]

As you can see from the 4yr rolling estimate: the constant moves a LOT, and typically in the direction of change in the LHS variable (lagging the changes a little).

I was worried about autocorrelation & some of the diagnostics — so I used HAC (Newey-West) standard errors.

data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szoexnnsqxo5d8s/ustToy.csv)

I have three questions:

1. What does the trending constant in the recursive estimation suggest?
2. Does the use of HAC standard errors help?
3. What estimators ought I to consider?

Comment: What is the model? (Time series is a type of data, not a type of model.) Without knowing the model, it is difficult to suggests estimators.

Comment: It is a model that contains monthly observations of bond yields (which have been trending down for the best part of a decade) on the LHS and some potential explanatory variables on the RHS. Estimated using OLS. No lags.

Answer (score 3):

A model with no lags or differences and no arima structure is often a NO-NO when you have time series data due to untreated auto-correlation . Time series analysis model identification enables more powerful model structure to be used. See https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf for a good introduction.  Perhaps you could explicitly present not only your model BUT the actual data in a csv format to facilitate further discussion .

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF YOUR DATA 246 MONTHLY VALUES (US10yr) starting 2005/1 WITH 3 POSSIBLE PREDICTORS:

What does the trending constant in the recursive estimation suggest?

My ans to question 1

1  in a univariate setting a shifting of the mean

2) in a causal setting ..not much can be said

I took your 246 values and found that a useful model required Weighted Estimation as the error variance was markedly lower in the most recent data. The model is here [image] with a supporting scatter plot of Y and your 3rd candidate predictor.

The Actual/Fit and Forecast is here [image]

If you can predict X3 that will aid your prediction of Y

Comment: Note that OLS is an estimation technique while model structure considers the definition of the model itself, thus it is questionable if they can be contrasted.

Comment: since the OP said no lags and no reference to identifiable deterministic structure I to I inferred ( perhaps incorrectly) that his model specification might be suspect.

Comment: I am not questioning the structure you inferred but rather the comparison of a model with an estimation technique. I find it helpful to keep the distinction clear.

Comment: @IrishStat added a chart and some data. thanks for your help.

Comment: Two questions: how does one decide when it is time to switch to weighted GLS? Also there’s the remaining question about HAC standard errors?

Comment: The idea behind detecting change points in the  error variance and thus the weights to use to normalize the error variance is presented here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html . I can not help with your question about HAC ....sorry